# SQLite3 escapeString failing, multiple single quotes generated

Tags: php, sqlite

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$text = $_POST['body'];
$id = SQLite3::escapeString($id);
$text = SQLite3::escapeString($text);

$query = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO messageTable (messageId, userId, body) VALUES ('$id', '$userId', '$text')";

$db->query($query);
```

The answer provided here [escaping strings for SQLite3 in PHP5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501351/escaping-strings-for-sqlite3-in-php5) is not good for me, as I can't use PDO.

The above code always doubles the number of single quotes when a string has single quotes. For instance, `I'm asking a question in 'stackoverflow'` will result in `I''m asking a question in ''stackoverflow''`

Comment: What error do you get with the generated escaping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `'` character is the escape character for the `'` character in SQLite (and some other databases):

[SQL As Understood By SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes
>   ('). **A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two
>   single quotes in a row** - as in Pascal. C-style escapes using the
>   backslash character are not supported because they are not standard
>   SQL.

Comment: Correct, this is the expected behavior. Is your code having any problems (throwing exceptions, not inserting rows in the database, not inserting what you expect in the database)?

Comment: My teacher provided me of that code, it's working but one of the questions I have to answer is stating that this double single quotes thing is an error and how could I fix it.

Comment: @CodingHater What is the exact text of that question?

Comment: @CL I figured out what was the problem. Indeed, single quotes must be escaped this way, so the point of this question is resolved. The question I have to answer now seems to be related with the code itself, not with the escaping function, so that's another question I will ask for help later if I need to.